# Get properties from a dynamic type

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, .net-4.0

i have a dynamic type

```
var f = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<dynamic>("CALL iv_sp_computersbyday();
```

how i can now what properties have the dynamic tuype returned??? i cant acces by reflection on the dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ExecuteStoreQuery but there is a difference between using the dynamic keyword and the object actually being a Dynamic Object. If it's a static object that is just cast as dynamic, then reflection will work just fine. If it's a Dynamic Object then reflection will return methods just not the ones you'd be expecting. Generally a Dynamic Object will have some way to query the parameters that are used to handle the implementation, for example things that inherit from `DynamicObject` often implement `GetDynamicMemberNames` and then has methods to invoke dynamically like `TryGetMember`. There are more general ways to do the dynamic binding once you have member names but it can be a little much to use with the DLR CallSites and Binders, although there are some simple static methods that encapsulate all the DLR stuff in the open source framework [Impromptu-Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/).